# Extracting all fields from java class

Tags: java, reflection

I was wondering if there was a easy way to get all defined fields and their types in a given class. This would be easy if the class were to contain only primitive types.

Ex

```
public class A
{
    int aX;
    String aS;
};

public class B
{
    int bX;
    String bS;
    A aObj;
};

public Class C
{
    boolean bC;
    B bObj;
};
```

Given C's class I would like extract all fields recursively (aX,aS,bX,bS,bC etc..).
Although this isn't particularly difficult to achieve, wanted to know if there are any existing libraries that I could leverage something like the jackson json which I think would have some utility functions which would achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be:

```
public static void run(Class c) {
  for(Field f : c.getFields()) {
    if(!f.getType().isPrimitive())
      System.out.println(f.getName());
    else
      run(f.getType());
  }
}
```

Using external libraries - especially in Java - is not a good idea if you only use a small part of it. The extra compiling and loading makes your program slower than it needs to be, and takes up too much space to be worth it.

Reference: [Java API on Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

Comment: This doesn't solve his problem. He wants to get all the Fields from all the Classes that are embedded in the class. You need to check each `Field` to see if it is an Object itself and then check the Fields for that Class as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... but this code wouldn't work for cases where one of the variable is Set<B>. f.getType would return Set.

Comment: @jack_carver Do you want it to iterate through the `Set`? Or just know that a `Set` is there?

Comment: Actually both :-), I am just trying to completely unmarshall the class skeleton so that I can dynamically enter values (user given) into the object. For ex: I would like to add cObj.bObj[0].aObj.aX = 3; (assuming bObj is an array instead of Set).

Comment: @jack_carver then you can just read the `Field` and re-set the object with the modified value.